# Unable to create DBeaver DB connection. Can't "open" a file, only "save"

Tags: dbeaver

When I click "New Database Connection" > "SQLite" it opens up the "Connect to a database" wizard. When I click "Browse" to load my db file's path, I don't have the option to "Open" my file. I can only "Save" a file. What am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: I'm having this exact sam issue on my Mac using the M1 version of DBeaver

Answer (score 1):

Just rollback to Version 21.3.0.202111281534, problem solved.

Comment: FYI, the Version 21.3.0.202111281534 download link is [here](https://download.dbeaver.com/community/21.3.0/dbeaver-ce-21.3.0-macos-x86_64.dmg) for Mac OS Intel user.